# Use PHP to get callback from GPIO in

Tags: python, pi-3, php, output

Is there a way to use PHP instead of python to detect callback from a GPIO pin? I see you can use shell_exec to execute a pin but not read output in real-time. An example is using a vibration sensor and detecting that sensor in real-time using ajax so I can see when the sensor vibrates via my browser hence the need for php.. I do not want to use a GUI library as I am most familiar with php.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [phpi](https://github.com/calcinai/phpi), it allows event binding to GPIO and is written in pure PHP.

There's also [an example](https://github.com/calcinai/phpi-websocket) to interface realtime via WebSockets which should solve the problem nicely.

*Disclosure: I am the author of the library*

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no library to use PHP to manipulate the GPIO in that manner. I've seen one basic library, but it doesn't support using callbacks.

I would recommend using Python for this portion of your backend.

Comment: Ya thats what im using now, just not familiar with it enough..with php I can add users and expand the game easily..